# Ubuntu 16.04 / Windows 10 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot

So I built a desktop and loaded Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10.  Everything worked wonderfully for about six months and then we had a baby.  I didn't log into Windows for nearly a year and when I tried recently, it didn't work. Typical response is that Grub comes up, I select Windows 10 and I get a blank purple screen that just hangs.  Other times, I'll get a Windows diagnostic screen that allows me to try to "repair my PC."  I ran the Ubuntu Boot Repair at one point with no success. Nothing seems to work.

Complicating issues is said baby.  I have maybe a half an hour every night to work on this, so it's been tough dedicating some effort.  So I apologize for my lackluster information here.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting directly from the windows hd/partition?  I hit f12 for my motherboard and it brings up a list of all the hard drives.  From that list select the windows one (there might be two, one labled UEFI, try both).  If you haven't logged on in a year you'll probably have to update.  You might want to set your bios to boot first from the windows drive till you have this resolved because a lot of times windows reboots while updating or repairing.

Congrats on the baby. I know the drill ;-)